# Custom Setter for Strong, Copy, weak and assign with atomic and nonatomic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Like this is Setter of COPY for nonatomic

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *someString;

-(void)setSomeString:(NSString *)someString {
  _someString = someString;
  _someString = [someString copy];
}
```

Like this I want to know the setter and getter for Strong, Weak and assign

```
@property (copy, atomic) NSString *someString; // Setter ?
@property (Strong, nonatomic) NSString *someString;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *someString;
@property (Strong, atomic) NSString *someString;
@property (assign, atomic) NSString *someString;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ex : setter method

```
- (void)setImgView:(UIImageView *)imgView{
    if (_imgView == imgView) {
        return;
    }
    _imgView = imgView;
    _imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    _imgView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
    _imgView.layer.cornerRadius = _imgView.frame.size.width/2;
}
```